# How to change my future method into stream method?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im displaying my videos collection where each video has a ratingbarfield. The Videos are displayed inside streambuilder.So my problem is that my method is a future method I need to change that into a stream also .
Heres my method

```
  onTap: () async {
                                
                                           
                                            } else {
                                              final value =
                                                  await FirebaseFirestore
                                                      .instance
                                                      .collection("videos")
                                                      .doc(videos.data()['id'])
                                                      .collection("uservotes")
                                                      .doc(uid)
                                                      .get();
                                              setState(() {
                                                votefromfirebase =
                                                    value.data()["rating"];

                                                israting = true;
                                              });
                                            } 
                                          },
```

Hope anyone can help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `FirebaseFirestore` the `CollectionReference` and `DocumentReference` provide a `snapshots()` method which returns a Stream:

```
final videoDocumentStream = await FirebaseFirestore
               .instance
               .collection("videos")
               .doc(videos.data()['id'])
               .collection("uservotes")
               .doc(uid)
               .snapshots();
```

to listen for a stream it is likely to use a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html):

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: videoDocumentStream.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        var userDocument = snapshot.data();
        return Text(userDocument["rating"]);
      },
    )
```

Comment: it says The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'

Comment: Set `()` after `snapshot.data`, corrected.

Comment: it sys Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: call()